# Cannot use absolute path to a file received via STDIN in PHP CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

As a part of some automation scripts I'm writing a function that asks the user for an absolute path to the file she wishes to use. The problem is that PHP throws `Warning: fopen("/path/to/desired/file/file.txt"): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/my/script/script.php on line 13` when the user inserts the file. Here is the general function:

```
function askFile() {

  echo "Please specify the full path to your file.\n";
  $usrInput = trim(fgets(STDIN, 1024));
  $usrInput = '"' . $usrInput . '"';
  echo $usrInput . "\n"; // Just to test the final string.

  echo is_string($usrInput) ? "It's a string.\n" : "It's not a string.\n"; // Just to confirm that the variable holds a string.

  if($handle = fopen($usrInput, 'r')) {
    echo "Thank you. The file is now opened.\n";
  } else {
    "Sorry, could not open the file for reading.\n";
  }

 }

askFile();
```

The permissions for the file are, for testing purposes, wide open at 777. When I simply hard code the absolute path right inside `fopen()` everything works as expected, therefore the problem only occurs when the input comes from *STDIN*.

Comment: `$usrInput = '"' . $usrInput . '"';` Did you notice that you are changing the file name here?

Comment: I've already tried without the quotes as well, just to be sure. But I left them there because the idea is not expect the user to type the path in double quotes and I'd need them to be passed to fopen(). Haven't coded the logic for cases where the user may insert her own quotes yet, though. Additionally, I'm echoing it back as test exactly to be sure about what is going into fopen().

Comment: You don't need to add the quotes to a variable to use it in a function. The quotes are needed only when you hard code the value.

Comment: Oh, my... I know it. Yet I was messing the interpolation. I'm gonna test again soon. Thanks!